# What is $c$ which set the test critical value of hypothesis testing?

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

A PDF of a random variable $X$ is $$f(x|\theta)=max({0,1-|x-\theta|})$$ Real number $\theta$ is a unknown parameter. I consider the hypothesis testing of a level of  $$\alpha(0\lt\alpha\leq0.05)\\\ H_0:\theta=0 \\\ H_1:\theta\neq0$$ We reject the $H_0$ when it is found to be $|X|\gt c$.

What is a value of $c$?

---

I set $$P(|max({0,1-|x-\theta|}|)>c|\theta=0)=\alpha \\\ P((|max{0,1-|x|}|)>c)=\alpha$$

but could not move on from here. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What you wrote is not right. You want to find the $c$ so that $P(|X|>c\mid \theta=0)=\alpha.$ The PDF tells you how to compute $P(|X|>c)$, which is the area of the tails.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen how can I incorporate that with condition $\theta=0$?

Comment: That tells you $\theta=0$ in the PDF, when you write down the integral for $P(|X|>c\mid \theta=0).$